# react setState change width accord input value

Tags: reactjs

follow this example on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoaxsCi13yQ#t=17m12s

I tried to have an input that change 'width' in the state, and then see the div get changed.  Here my code:

```
import  React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class TestColors extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      width: 300,
    };
  }
  handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      width: event.target.value,
    }));
  }
  render() {
    const style = {
      backgroundColor: 'orange',
      width: this.state.width,
    };

    return (
      <div style={style}>
        <input onChange="this.handleInputChange"/> {this.state.width}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

but i get this error on the render:

```
warning.js:35 Warning: Failed form propType: Invalid prop `onChange` of type `string` supplied to `input`, expected `function`. Check the render method of `TestColors`
```

when i change the input value i get this error:

```
LinkedValueUtils.js:132 Uncaught TypeError: inputProps.onChange.call is not a function
    at Object.executeOnChange (LinkedValueUtils.js:132)
    at ReactDOMComponent._handleChange (ReactDOMInput.js:241)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (ReactErrorUtils.js:69)
    at executeDispatch (EventPluginUtils.js:85)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (EventPluginUtils.js:108)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (EventPluginHub.js:43)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (EventPluginHub.js:54)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at forEachAccumulated (forEachAccumulated.js:24)
    at Object.processEventQueue (EventPluginHub.js:254)
```

I don't know why a lof of examples on the website use (without prevState):

```
  handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState( {
      width: event.target.value,
    });
  }
```

and not:

```
  handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      width: event.target.value,
    }));
  }
```

is there an difference?  why i the input does not update the label with the value and the width, i need redux for that ?

After reading this link i start to think that  setState is the devil with a lot of problems in the react cycle update:

https://medium.com/javascript-scene/setstate-gate-abc10a9b2d82

but i did not find yet a clear reply on internet, blogs, etc, anyone maybe habe the key to understand this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in onClick you want to call a javaScript function you need to wrap function call in `{}` instead of `""`, because function is javascript and in jsx we wrap javascript inside `{}` So make a change in your jsx as:

```
<input onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
```

What actually happened was it was expecting a function and you provided it a string, so gave an error.

**EDIT :** As you mentioned the different way using setState function, the syntax is wrong. Instead use it like :

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      width: event.target.value,
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks now I'm having a new error, it's seems, my event is inside Setstate? Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist()